# SQLite encryption in bb10

Tags: sqlite, encryption, blackberry-10

I need to know if there is a way I could encrypt my **entire** db in the for the blackberry 10 OS , since I try to transfer my android app to BB10.From my search on the internet I have not found anything usefull that could help. I do know that the blackberry 10 has a uses a great encryption by default, but I want to know if there is something more I could use.

I need something that could work like [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/), which I used on Android. Any backup plan which I could use?

Cheers.

Comment: Did you try to compile SQLCypher for BB10?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to understand what you really want:

- Do you want to package your app using the Android Runtime (the apk to bar conversion)

> One of the big limits of the Blackberry Android runtime is that you
>   can’t use native libraries. It seems that SQLCypher is native, so you
>   won’t be able to use it. I see two alternatives:
>
> - Make sure that you application saves the SQL DB to secure storage, and trust BlackBerry.
> - Find a work-around, encrypting values of your database or working    with a memory-backed database and encrypting data while you serialize 
>     it.

Or

- Do you want to port your android application to Cascades
  Short answer is that you can compile and bundle any library you want with your BB10 application.

> You should try to compile SQLCypher for BB10. OpenSSL (libcrypto) is
>   already part of the SDK, so you should be able to use that.
>
> Use the shortcuts installed with the BB10 SDK to launch a terminal
>   with the SDK env variables, to compile SQLCypher.
>
> Then, once you have your libraries (.so) and headers (.h), copy them
>   into your project to use them. One minor complication is that the
>   emulator uses x86 whereas the devices use arm code, so you’ll have to
>   make sure that your “.pro” file and the “bar-descriptor.xml” takes
>   those case into account.

Comment: I am already using the first approach. Unfortunately I can not work with a memory-backed database since my database is huge and it would get a lot of resources. The second approach is a bad choise because, then it would mean I shoud write the same project from the stratch.

Comment: I almost made add a link to pure-java qslite implementation like [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) but it occurred to me that:
1) You would lose Android bindings, so you would have to rewrite a lot of code
2) You would have to make a clone of SQLCypher.
3) Performance would be horrible.
All BB10 handsets come with 16GB of memory, so BB secure storage may be enough.
Also, there is an update to the Android runtime coming. Maybe support of native libs…